# SQL Multiple Left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called documents with a row called Nigel Harding

```
DOCUMENTS
id | label
24 | Nigel Harding
```

He has been tagged with two other documents one with an ID of 1 & 12 that table is called document tags

```
DOCUMENT_TAGS
id | label | Document_id
1 | TAG A | 24
12 | TAG B | 24
```

I am trying to create a query where I can find one result where Nigel Harding will appear once if searching for the tags **1 AND 12** but i'm having no luck.

I figured out the query for searching one tag id but i'm trying to do the query for both tags.

```
SELECT documents.id 
FROM documents 
LEFT JOIN documents_tags 
ON documents.id=documents_tags.document_id 
WHERE documents_tags.tag_id = 1 ORDER BY documents.label
```

I understand why adding...

```
AND documents_tags.tag_id = 12
```

...to the end of that will not work but i'm not sure what i need to do get the correct query display my one result as my understanding of SQL is very basic.

Comment: It's just `AND ...`, not `AND WHERE ...`.

Comment: The reason `AND` doesn't work is because a single row will never have both 1 and 12 for a value in `tag_id`

Comment: Thats why there is an OR:  documents_tags.tag_id = 1 or documents_tags.tag_id = 12 or more simple documents_tags.tag_id in (1,12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most flexible way to approach this type of problem is to use aggregation with a `having` clause.  Here is one example:

```
SELECT dt.document_id 
FROM documents_tags dt
GROUP BY dt.document_id
HAVING sum(dt.tag_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(dt.tag_id = 12) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of document tags that are 1 (or 12) and the filter passes only when both are found.  You could also write this as:

```
SELECT dt.document_id 
FROM documents_tags dt
WHERE dt.tag_id in (1, 12)
GROUP BY dt.document_id
HAVING count(distinct dt.tag_id) = 2;
```

Comment: This seems to be close to what i needed but instead of grouping by dt.id i needed to group by document_id

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you're just lacking `IN` and `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT documents.id 
FROM documents 
LEFT JOIN documents_tags 
ON documents.id=documents_tags.document_id 
WHERE documents_tags.tag_id IN (1, 12) ORDER BY documents.label
```

Using `IN` you'll be getting documents for any of the tag ids specified, and using `DISTINCT` you'll make sure to get each document id only once.

---

**EDIT:** Since you're ordering by documents.label, I'm guessing that's what you want displayed. Don't forget you can change your `SELECT` statement to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT documents.label
```

or even to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT documents.id, documents.label
```

Comment: @Luke If you give me more information (why is my solution not working for you?) I might be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this (adjusted to search by tag label which I think is your goal, if not just replace dt.Label = 'etc' with dt.ID = etc):

```
    SELECT documents.id 
    FROM documents d
    WHERE 
    exists (select dt.id from documents_tags dt 
where dt.document_id = d.document_id and dt.label = 'TAG A')
    AND
    exists (select dt.id from documents_tags dt 
where dt.document_id = d.document_id and dt.label = 'TAG B')
```

Answer (score 0):

one `WHERE` word is enough:

```
SELECT documents.id 
FROM documents 
LEFT JOIN documents_tags 
ON documents.id=documents_tags.document_id 
WHERE (documents_tags.tag_id = 1 OR documents_tags.tag_id = 12) ORDER BY documents.label
```

alternatively, if you are going to work with n different tags and don't want to add `OR documents_tags.tag_id = x` ever time you can use `IN` operator

```
SELECT documents.id 
FROM documents 
LEFT JOIN documents_tags 
ON documents.id=documents_tags.document_id 
WHERE documents_tags.tag_id IN(1,12) ORDER BY documents.label
```

Comment: The first example still doesn't work; that could return records that only have 1 or 12

Comment: No row will match both conditions of tag_id=1 and tag_id=12. It will not return any rows at all.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, you are right, I'm not sure that's what OP is asking and leave this here in case he needs this answer. that version is also posted anyway.

Comment: i fixed that problem @RaviH.

Comment: None of those seem to work because it seems like its doing an OR rather than AND because I am seeing multiple results. There should only be one document with both the tags 1 & 12

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to aggregate the results when you search for multiple document tags, so you should use `GROUP BY`, which is for grouping multiple rows into one row:

```
SELECT documents.id 
FROM documents
LEFT JOIN documents_tags ON documents.id = documents_tags.document_id
WHERE documents_tags.tag_id IN (1, 12)
GROUP BY documents.id
```

This will give you one row for each document that matches the given tag ids.  And you can generalize to any list of tag ids by adding to the list without too much pain.  You could even add a `COUNT(*)` to the select statement to find out how many tag ids where matched for the given document.